# How does Lean4 (or a typical PA) represent lambda functions or in other words arbitrary expressions?

Tags: lean4, lambda-calculus, soft-question, programming-languages, abstract-syntax-tree

#### Question:

Say I wanted my language to support various operator symbols, the semantics of which are defined by the user or by axioms.

> I'm wondering whether Lean4 (or a typical well-known PA) just stores new kinds of operation expressions as strings, lists, expression trees or...?  Could you link me to the specific part in the Lean4 code that defines these classes or structs?

I'm fairly certain that it doesn't implement a new class in its kernel for each operator, because it supports almost any Unicode string as an operator symbol (?)

So what data structure does lean use internally to represent the expressions that are the definition part of its lambda functions.  I'm assuming it's based upon Lambda functions, because it's Type Theory-based, and usually or so I thought each of those systems appeals to these types expressions.

I am not sure whether I'll support every operator under the sun, but I at least want every operator appearing in *Algebra* by Serge Lang, for example.  Well, they don't mention wreath product in that book, so in essence, your typical math book plus a few exotic operators.  But it should be straight-forward to add in new operators, i.e. not a week-or-more of debugging to get them to work.

*You can stop reading here, the below is just extra information*

---

I'm not going to represent things as Unicode as Lean4 does, instead I'm going the LaTeX approach.  Everything the user types in, there is a live preview that renders LaTeX / Markdown.  If anyone is interested, the canonical example of such an editor (with no PA or any kind of math backend) is:

[Marked / KaTeX rendering from within a Qt/C++ app](https://github.com/enjoysmath/Marked-KaTeX-example-cpp)

I did not come up with that on my own.  It's an example provided by Qt, the markdown portion.  I did add in support for KaTeX, but it was easy.  If you'd like say to add in support for the Quiver editor on the JS side, you'd have to figure out how the QWebChannel communication code works.

#### My Background:

I know a lot of math (check out my MSE profile).  I have been coding for over 10 years.  I know the essentials to get a DSL or programming language up and running, but have never actually finished & publically shared one.  The D language has this nice parser generator called pegged, which allows you to specify PEG grammars. I am intermediate at it.  It's a lot more user friendly to me than ANTLR or bison / lex.  I  by no means want to compete with Lean4 or anything.  My goal is to do diagram chase-based proofs, but of course I need to support at least polynomials, and then a can of worms is opened into the world of PA's.  I have coded many frontends for diagram editors, but always seem to get stuck on the logical backend or the PA-related system.  A book recommendation would be nice.  I think I want to stick with natural deduction and set theory axioms, and not delve into Type Theory quite yet.  I would like the presentation of my system to be as close of a match to mathematics as-you-see-it in rigorous, formal-yet-human-readable textbooks.

So what I lack is "formalized logic theory" knowledge, Compiler Design, Type Theory knowledge.  I figured I am good enough of a programmer to tackle what I need to, though, without taking graduate-level courses to understand some of this stuff.  I figure, if I know math and I know how to program, then I should be able to come up with *something*.  Just *something* that would be of value to mathematical users.

Comment: I don’t think this is a well thought out question.  What is an “operator symbol” in Latex?  You could be conceivably asking about how lean’s logic stores expressions, how the pretty print works, how elaboration works, or a number of other related questions.  Here are the [docs for the expression type](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Lean/Expr.html#Lean.Expr).  Here is the [paper on Lean 3’s meta framework](https://leanprover.github.io/papers/tactic.pdf).

Comment: Also see this question: https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/1542/algorithm-for-the-locally-nameless-representation-used-by-lean

Comment: As for operator symbols, I’m not sure what your first paragraph has to do with the second, or why you are focused on operators like +.  Lean has to handle all custom functions like `list.map`.  It also has to handle all custom notations, including operators like +, but also a lot more.  The really short answer is that when you enter code into Lean, it gets parsed and stored as expressions and related types.  Conversely, when Lean needs to show you internal expressions (like goals in the middle of a tactic proof), the pretty printer turns expressions into readable pretty printed code.

Comment: Perhaps you may be interested in principles of compiler design. But without further information on your background knowledge it is hard to say.

Comment: Are you asking how a proof assistant is implemented? That's an art of itself, quite close to implementation of programming languages. Lean is essentially a programming language, and in programming languages one can define new types/classes/functions etc. We can give you some pointers and tutorials, but I'd like to understand first what you're asking.

Comment: It's very difficult to tell what you're asking here. A good exercise would be to rephrase your question without invoking Latex or C++

Comment: A brief look at the source on GitHub and it looks like the Lean4 parser is entirely in Lean, bootstrapped using a compiler written in Lean which generates C. This means the parsed representation is going to be a Lean data structure, not C++; I expect the actual in-memory data would be a classic pointer based graph, but I haven't looked closely enough. You could [use Lean](https://leanprover.github.io/lean4/doc/syntax.html) to implement or prototype your language (maybe you're planning to write your own proof assistant in, say, C++?)

Comment: Again, implementing a programming language or a proof assistant requires a certain skill set. I very much encourage people to make their own proof assistants, but not without looking around to learn basic techniques. So, what are you really after?

Comment: I will have to edit my post this weekend. Thank you all for your guidance and links.

Comment: @DanielMGessel close: the D language. So that I don't have to worry about memory leaks.  I've already tried C++ before and things got way too hairy with smart pointers etc., which I'm not used to using.  I couldn't see a way to do it without smart pointers because of the different ways I was sharing objects and there wasn't a clear "owner" for an attached member.

Comment: I guess I should have an expression class hierarchy, but with the ability to change the operator, and not name the classes after a fixed operator.

Comment: The frontend, however, will be Qt/C++ desktop for now, but mobile later on.

Comment: Okay, PA community.  I've edited.  Let me know what else I can do to clarify this question.

Comment: Your demo is nice! I'm oriented to bits and bytes, and always curious about memory management. I found a paper co-authored by Leonardo de Moura [Counting Immutable Beans: Reference Counting Optimized for Purely Functional Programming](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.05647) which will help me update my 1990's perspective on GC. I started to read the doc, [Theorem Proving in Lean 4](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean4/), Jason Rute linked to below, but it's clear "proofs as programs" is going to take me some time. Starting with some propositional logic toys is the right fit for me.

Comment: @DanielMGessel Thanks.  Perhaps someone else can link you to the Holbert interactive textbook demo about that topic (natural deduction + propositional logic).  Also look into Benjamin Pierce's book about types and programming languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This answer assumes you already know some of the basics of Lean as in [Theorem Proving in Lean 4](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean4/).)

In a typical first logic class or set theory class in college, first order logic is presented as taking place in a particular language (or signature).  ZFC for example is in the language with only one binary relation $\in$.  (The basic logic operations and quantifiers are also assumed usually, including $\exists$, $\forall$, $\rightarrow$, $\land$, $\lor$, $\neg$ and $\leftrightarrow$ as well as parenthesis and variables). All other definitions are just abbreviations for a longer expression.  However, in practical proof assistants this isn't practical. We must have the ability to make definitions (and theorems, axioms, etc) first class citizens.

The way Lean (and I assume Coq and Agda) do this is to store declarations.  In Lean the type [`Declaration`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Lean/Declaration.html#Lean.Declaration) can be any of the following:

- axioms
- definitions
- theorems
- ...

A [Definition](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Lean/Declaration.html#Lean.DefinitionVal) is made up of the following parts:

- the name of the definition
- the type of the definition
- the value of the definition (i.e. the body of the definition after the `:=` in Lean)

...as well as some more technical details.  [Theorems](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Lean/Declaration.html#Lean.TheoremVal) are similar, except the type is the statement of the theorem and the value is the proof.  (In dependent type theory, unlike other logics, definitions and theorems are mostly the same thing, with the differences being mostly technical details in how each is implemented and stored.)

Going down the rabbit hole, the type and value of a definition or theorem is an expression [Expr](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Lean/Expr.html#Lean.Expr).  Before going into Lean expressions, let's recall expressions in a simpler logic like propositional logic.  In propositional logic, a well-formed-formula (wff) is defined (inductively) to be any of the following forms:

- a propositional variable $P$
- a negation $(\neg \phi)$, for an wff $\phi$
- $(\phi \square \psi)$ for $\square$ in $\rightarrow$, $\land$, $\lor$, $\neg$ and $\leftrightarrow$ and wffs $\phi$ and $\psi$.

The idea of a Lean expression is similar, except that it doesn't make sense to hard code the logical symbols like `\land`.  Ignoring notation and unicode characters in Lean, the way that Lean would represent `and P Q` would first use Currying to represent it as `(and P) Q` and then use an applicative operator to represent that as `app (app and P) Q`.  The applicative operator `app fn arg` means apply the function `fn` to the argument `arg`.  The major exception to this in Lean is `->` (both the logical implication and the function arrow as in `Nat -> Nat` since they are the same thing).  `A -> B` is just an abbreviation for `forall (_ : A), B` or `Pi (_ : A), B`.

Now for more of the specifics.  An [Expr](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Lean/Expr.html#Lean.Expr) can be any of the following:

- a *bound variable* `bvar n`, where `n` is a number (the DeBruijn index) saying how many levels one has to go up to get to the corresponding quantifier.  This has many advantages over storing the variable name directly.
- a *free variable* `fvar nm` where `nm` is a unique name for that free variable.
- a *sort* `sort lvl` where `lvl` is the level of that sort, e.g. `Prop` is level zero, `Type` is level one, `Type u` has level `u+1` where `u` is a universe variable)
- a *constant* `const nm` where `nm` is the name of some definition, theorem, axiom, etc already in the library.
- an *applicative* `app fn arg` where `fn` is the expression for the function and `arg` is the expression for the argument of the function.
- a *lambda* expression `lam nm tp body bi` where `nm` is the name of the variable for that lambda binder, `tp` is the expression for the type of that variable, `body` is an expression for the body of the lambda (which might use that variable), and `bi` is some technical information about what kind of binder it is.
- a *forall/Pi* expression `forallE nm tp body bi` where `nm`, `tp`, `body`, and `bi` are just like in lambda expressions.

...as well as a few more less-used expression types.

---

There are many more implementation details to Lean.  For example, [type classes](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean4/type_classes.html) and [notation](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean4/interacting_with_lean.html?highlight=notation#notation) are what let you use infix operators like `+` or list notation like `[1, 2, 3]` (as well as representing numbers as digits).

Turning human code into Lean expressions is a process known as *elaboration*.  (Actually, I'm not positive on the differences between parsing, elaboration, and type checking. Although I do know that *type checking* is what checks that an expression is valid, and is also what checks that a proof is valid in Lean.)

Conversely, if you have an expression inside Lean, like the goal of a state in a tactic proof, the *pretty-printer* is what prints that expression in a form which is human readable Lean code.

The Lean 3 meta framework (similar to Lean 4's I believe) is described in the paper [A Metaprogramming Framework for Formal Verification](https://leanprover.github.io/papers/tactic.pdf).

---

Ok, how would you implement all of the above?  If you know functional programming, e.g. Scala, Haskell, OCaml, or even Lean 4 (which is a fully featured functional programming language itself used to implement Lean), then this should appear familiar to you. Declarations, expressions, universe levels, etc are all just implemented as [inductive data types](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean4/inductive_types.html?highlight=inductive#inductive-types) (or what some functional languages call [algebraic data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type)).  A good exercise is to code up in your favorite functional programming language the data types of well-formed formulas in propositional logic as I described above.

If you aren't working in a functional language, but instead in a low level language like C, then I think you would have to consult the best practices for your language, and just look up "how do I implement algebraic data structures in X language".  However, Lean 4 is implemented in C++ as well.  (Specifically, C++ is used to boot-strap Lean 4 so you can build Lean 4 in Lean 4.)  I think expressions are implemented in the file [`expr.h`](https://github.com/leanprover/lean4/blob/master/stage0/src/kernel/expr.h).

---

This is only scratching the surface, but hopefully it gives you a flavor and some references and keywords to explore on your own.

Comment: Regarding elaboration, the terminology is somewhat blurry, but I would make the following distinctions. Parsing takes a literal string, and interprets this string into a representation of your code that programs can reasonably manipulate (typically, an abstract syntax tree). Elaboration takes code in some (structured representation of an) input syntax which is nice for users, and turns it into code in a "core" syntax which is nice for the computer and/or the meta-theory. Type-checking takes code in the core syntax, and checks that it is well-typed.

Comment: While this sounds like three different steps that can be separated, in practice this can be more complicated. Typically, elaboration looks like a beefed-up version of type-checking, as it uses type information to perform its translation. More subtly, you might want type-aware notations, which means that you need to have some interaction between parsing (responsible for notations) and elaboration. However, having strong interdependence between the different phases makes them harder to code, which is why some systems still try and enforce some separation.